# Replace element on click, and return it on click at another place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to turn a div into an input when user clicks on it, and backwards when user clicks on another place. Here's what I managed to do:

http://plnkr.co/edit/afywWZL0O6xLuE1IXDRN?p=preview

If you click on the div with the magnifier picture, it will turn into an input, but there are two things that need to be fixed.

The first problem is that you cannot use this input, as once you click on it, it becomes a div again. I added stopPropagation() to both form and input, hoping that it will prevent unwanted replacement, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$(".search-input").on("click", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(".search-form").on("click", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

The second trouble is that when you try to test it and click on the magnifier, and then on blank area at the right, you can do it only once. It seems to me that when you create a div with a "search" class and make the replacement, jQuery doesn't work with it anymore.

So I have two questions: **why doesn't stopPropagation() work here, and why is div with a "search" class replaced only once?**

Comment: the reason you cannot do the same thing twice, is because you create a new element, that has the same class, but that dit not exist when you created the elements array, on dom ready. If you want the new element to have the same behavior, you should reinitiate the eventListeners.

Comment: Yep. You can also use jQ event delegation as well to bind the event.

Comment: you could relay on focus and contenteditable attribute : CSS example http://plnkr.co/edit/Rkea8NtOFLNivmlTDN9G?p=preview you can add/turn it into js to make it bullet proof....

Answer (score 0):

Use body as a reference for your clicks

```
$(body).on("click", ".search-input", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(body).on("click", ".search-form", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```